# Search In Browser for results with spaces with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my programm:

```
import os
system=1
google=["search web","google search","help","google","open google","search google"]
while system==1:
  action=(input("What would you want me to do for you : "))
  googlesearch=("opera https://www.google.com/#q=")
  if any(word in action for word in google):
    actiongoogle=(input("What do you want me to google?: "))
    if actiongoogle=="nothing":
      print("Ok Then.")
    else:
      print("launching google");os.system(googlesearch+actiongoogle)
```

The program is running properly when the input is only 1 word , but when you leave some spaces , it opens new tabs and also it is not using the www.google.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you need to replace white space between words with '+'

```
import os
system=1
google=["search web","google search","help","google","open google","search google"]
while system==1:
  action=(input("What would you want me to do for you : "))
  googlesearch=("google-chrome https://www.google.com/#q=")
  if any(word in action for word in google):
      actiongoogle=(input("What do you want me to google?: "))
      if actiongoogle=="nothing":
          print("Ok Then.")
      else:
          print("launching google");
          s_s="+".join(actiongoogle.split())
          ls = s_s.replace(' ','+')
          os.system(googlesearch+ls)
```